# ASP.NET App_code Error handling

Tags: asp.net

I have many web applications with (ASP.NET) and i handle all errors using the "Global.asax" in Application_Error function, But some errors not catches by this way, so i create separate web application for handling such errors, and send in all my application in the WEB.Config file

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="http://errorhandel/errorpage.aspx?CRM=2"/>
```

My question now, if error occurs in one of my applications how i can know which one and which page fire this error.

Comment: Why not have a trace listener instead?

Answer (score 0):

Application_Error will always fire